# Oracle 10g import Error Quick Question

Tags: import, oracle10g

If import fails with errors thrown, does it mean that there will be some data imported successful while others are imported even though at the end of the import, it says import fails. If so, doesn't that mean that I would have duplicate objects if I try to import again ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

depends on the error and table . if the error is on one table only then other tables will probably be imported. the  answer willl be it depends